# Animation doesn't start before the opacity transition is complete in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, iframe, css-transitions, opacity

I've made a simple magnifying glass effect: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7LExF/). It's a div with the same background as the `<img>` source, that changes its position based on the pointer position while hovering over image. Nothing too complicated. In the Fiddle it works just fine in browsers that support `pointer-events: none;` (the rest doesn't make it disappear, but that's not the problem right now).

The problem is that in Chrome it works only when the code is inside `<iframe>`, like in that Fiddle. When it's not, just like here: [Fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7LExF/show/), the background of magnifying glass moves only after opacity transition is complete. I made it 1,5 second so it's easier to notice. What's also strange is that it partially works when I hover the cursor starting from the top of the image.

What may be the problem? Is there any other solution than putting that code inside iframe? I tried to modify the js and it kind of works with `fadeIn()/fadeOut()` with jQuery, but I'd rather have it done with opacity transition in CSS in this case.

And feel free to change the title so it makes more sense :)